# Rapidminer CSV read misses row and label name

Tags: csv, rapidminer

I tried to read the data from this CSV file but rapid miner shows me the wrong header and deleted the right header. I open this file with excel and the 4 row should be the header. Some cell is in 2 lines but rapid miner splits it into 2 cells.

https://files.ontario.ca/opendata/2536_bridge_conditions.csv

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a **[minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**. It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have **[tried so far](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding **[how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**, and take the **[tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)**

Answer (score 0):

The file contains multiline fields as well as a multiline header (row 4, spans 3 lines).

So you'll need to tell the parser the fields are multiline and quoted (`"`).

The csv file itself is valid.

Comment: Thank you for replying. when I input the data, I set comma as separation and use Quotes ( ") already. Is there any other setting I can tell the parser?

Comment: @CalvinDeng It looks like the parser doesn't handle multiline fields correctly, so maybe there's an option for that. I don't know rapidminer, so I can't help with specific settings.